# How can I detect idle time using socket.io?

Tags: node.js, session, socket.io

I've been reading about [socket timeout method using **net** module](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback). But I'd like to know if there is a similar mechanism in **socket.io** module to detect user's inactivity(10 minutes of inactivity through the socket, for example) to perform some actions with this session in server side or notify this event to other users.

Thank you in advance.